# Why do _site files still sometimes show for commiting?

Tags: git, jekyll

This is the top of my .gitignore

`### Jekyll ###
_site/
.sass-cache/
.jekyll-metadata`

It seems properly setup but I still get _site/ files showing in my GitKraken...

EDIT: here's the repo in question, thanks: https://github.com/BradCoffield/APIs-for-librarians

Comment: What else do you have on your `.gitignore`? Maybe some other rule is cancelling the removal of `_site` with some wildcard e.g. `_*/`?

Comment: Something else to test: Open a Git bash on your repository and check if you also see the `_sites` folder when you run a `git status` command. If you see that, the problem is likely with the `.gitignore`, if not, the problem is likely with GitKraken

Comment: Please share a link to the repository.

Comment: I edited my post to include the repo link. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.gitignore` file looks good. You might have added files in the '_site' folder before adding the `.gitignore` file. If you see the '_site' folder in your respository, then that is most likely the case. Just delete the '_site' folder from your repository and you should be good.

You can easily achieve this without actually deleting the folder using:

```
 git rm --cached _site
```

followed by a commit.

Comment: I suggest adding the minimal rm --cache to make this a proper answer.

Comment: @kabanus Feel free to do do.

Comment: @kabanus Thanks!